# How to construct WMI query

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, wmi, wmi-query, string.format

I'd like to find results that Name starts with param1, and ends with param2 but my code doesn't work

```
string wmiQuery = string.Format("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE '{0}%' AND Name LIKE '%{1}'", param1, param2);
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
ManagementObjectCollection retObjectCollection = searcher.Get();
```

What's wrong?

For comparision

```
string wmiQuery = string.Format("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE '{0}%'", param1);
```

works well

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of what you are expecting? And is it just returning an empty collection?

Comment: Not empty. Collection of processes whose name starts with the param1 and ends with param2. I get then their id

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
string wmiQuery = string.Format("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE '{0}%{1}'", param1, param2);
```

Adding some test info:

```
string wmiQuery = string.Format ( "SELECT Name, ProcessID FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE '{0}%{1}'", "wpf", ".exe" );

Console.WriteLine ( "Query: {0}", wmiQuery );

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher ( wmiQuery );
ManagementObjectCollection retObjectCollection = searcher.Get ( );

foreach (ManagementObject retObject in retObjectCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine ( "[{0}]\tName: {1}", retObject[ "ProcessID" ], retObject["Name"] );
}
```

Output:

> Query: SELECT Name, ProcessID FROM
>   Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE
>   'wpf%.exe'
>   [896]   Name: WPFFontCache_v0400.exe

Answer (score 10):

To build WMI queries use a free tool from Microsoft known as WMI Code Creator in different programming languages VBS, VB.NET, C#

Download it from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en

Comment: @Chad LOL why do you hate it?

Comment: @JordanRieger That was 3 years ago, I honestly don't remember...but I'm sure I had a good reason!