# what's the fast and new way(based on high performance) of reading event logs from remote machine using c#

Tags: c#, performance

I know this question has like 100's of similar questions. i have gone through most of them and they are outdated and doesn't seem to perform well.

I am trying to read event logs from remote computers using c#, the way which i am currently during is really slow (reading 60,000 logs) takes about 30 mins.

I am using

```
 EventLogReader Class
```

I have also tried Event Log Query and some WMI way.  But truly speaking they are all really slow.

There most be some other way of doing this. How can I read them faster?

Comment: What is your actual requirement?  30 minutes for 60,000 logs seems pretty speedy to me.  That's 2000 logs per minute, or about 33 per second.

Comment: how long does it take if run locally?

Comment: my actual requirement is to filter the log with event id and event source from the available logs. 30 mins is really slow

Comment: if its locally it takes about 4 mins

Comment: What is your *performance* requirement?

Comment: while reading those logs visual studio consumes about 2.25 GB of memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is faster, but worth a shot

My suggestion is to skip the eventlogreader class and go straight to WMI  ( where you may be able to query just what you want.

Also, you can get the remote machine to backup the event log then try copying the backup...

see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394593(v=vs.85).aspx

you may want to look at

[How to construct WMI query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264453/how-to-construct-wmi-query)

on how to do WMI From C#